# Windbg - can !for_each_frame be mimicked with a .for, .do or .while?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, windbg

`!for_each_frame` will iterate through each frame of a thread, and allow you to run a command (even a bunch of commands) on a single line.

Is there a way to do a simple loop in a Windbg script so that you can start at frame `00` of the current thread and iterate up to the last frame and do whatever you want to do in each frame within a nice multi-line, multi-step block of code?

This code will obviously iterate up, but it will never stop until you do a Debug - Break. That is true even if Windbg starts to report `Cannot find frame 0xXX, previous scope unchanged` so how might I be able to check for the condition I need?

```
.frame 0n0
.do
{
  .f+
}
(1==1)
```

Is there something I can retrieve and store before the `.do` starts, or some inbuilt thread token that I can check in the Condition, or some error condition which will be hit by `.f+`, as it traverses up to the higher frames, that I can just jump out on?

Comment: If I could access something like the in-built pseudo-register `@$frame`, but for the last / highest frame, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0:000> dx @$curstack.Frames.Count()
@$curstack.Frames.Count() : 0x4
0:000> .cxr;r $t0 = 0;.do { .f+ ; r $t0 = @$t0+1 } (@$t0 < 4 )
Resetting default scope
01 0014fa14 770060a7 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11a9
02 0014fa64 77003659 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x78
03 0014fa74 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
Cannot find frame 0x4, previous scope unchanged
03 0014fa74 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
```

Based on the comment by William Messmer you can assign a dx expression to a primitive Pseudo Register provided you employ it as dx

my earlier comment that says you cannot assign was based on this format
which doesn't work

```
.for( r $t0 = @$curstack.Frames.Count() ;......)
```

but here is the gotcha

you can use

```
**dx @$t0 = @$curstack.Frames.Count()** and use the Pseudo Register inside any loop variables
```

the pseudo register that's is assigned a value  doesn't result in an error

though this appears to be equivalent to making a user variable
like **dx @$foo = @$curStack.Frames.Count()**

it appears we cannot use the @$foo as a loop variable

here is simple poc based on the tests

**C:>cdb cdb

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86**

**0:000> dx @$t1 = @$curstack.Frames.Count()**

```
@$t1 = @$curstack.Frames.Count() : 0x4 [Type: unsigned __int64]
```

**0:000> .for(dx @$t0 =0 ; @$t0 < @$t1 ; r $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) { .frame @$t0 }**

```
@$t0 =0          : 0 [Type: int]
00 0012fad0 77000e00 ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c
01 0012fc30 76fe60a7 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11a9
02 0012fc80 76fe3659 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x78
03 0012fc90 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
```

**0:000> .cxr; dx @$t0 =0;.do { .f+ ; r $t0 = @$t0+1 } (@$t0 < @$t1 )**

```
Resetting default scope
@$t0 =0          : 0 [Type: int]
01 0012fc30 76fe60a7 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x11a9
02 0012fc80 76fe3659 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x78
03 0012fc90 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
Cannot find frame 0x4, previous scope unchanged
03 0012fc90 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
0:000>
```

**0:001> .for(dx @$t0 =0 ; @$t0 < @$t1 ; r $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) { .echo "hi" ; ?? ( @$t0 * 3.1415 ) }**

```
@$t0 =0          : 0 [Type: int]
hi
double 0
hi
double 3.1415000000000001812
hi
double 6.2830000000000003624
hi
double 9.4245000000000000995
hi
double 12.566000000000000725
hi
double 15.70750000000000135
hi
double 18.849000000000000199
hi
double 21.990500000000000824
hi
double 25.13200000000000145
hi
double 28.273500000000002075
hi
double 31.4150000000000027
0:001>
```

needs c++ not masm  for evaluation  using ?  it will err in syntax error

but making the constant c++ seems to evaluate

**0:001> .expr
Current expression evaluator: MASM - Microsoft Assembler expressions

0:001> .for(dx @$t0 =0 ; @$t0 < @$t1 ; r $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) { .echo "hi" ; ? ( @$t0 * 3.1415 ) }**

```
@$t0 =0          : 0 [Type: int]
hi
Syntax error at '3.1415 ) '
```

**0:001> .for(dx @$t0 =0 ; @$t0 < @$t1 ; r $t0 = @$t0 +1 ) { .echo "hi" ; ? ( @$t0 * @@c++(3.1415) ) }**

```
@$t0 =0          : 0 [Type: int]
hi
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000
hi
Evaluate expression: 3 = 00000003
hi
Evaluate expression: 6 = 00000006
hi
Evaluate expression: 9 = 00000009
hi
Evaluate expression: 12 = 0000000c
hi
Evaluate expression: 15 = 0000000f
hi
Evaluate expression: 18 = 00000012
hi
Evaluate expression: 21 = 00000015
hi
Evaluate expression: 24 = 00000018
hi
Evaluate expression: 27 = 0000001b
hi
Evaluate expression: 30 = 0000001e
```

Comment: This example of `.cxr;r $t0 = 0;.do { .f+ ; r $t0 = @$t0+1 } (@$t0 < 4 )` is a beautiful thing, but I cannot get anything from `@$curstack.Frames.Count()` apart from `Error: Use of undefined variable` - nor can I find anything about on the web; _maybe_ my version of Windbg here is a bit old, but I can try a newer version. I think that's it because `dx Debugger.State.DebuggerVariables` doesn't show anything about `curstack`.

Comment: Is `$curstack` only available in Windbg Preview? I cannot currently install that, seemingly, due to OS requirements. I don't see `curstack` returned when I try `dx Debugger.State.DebuggerVariables` on either of the two versions of Windbg I have access to - 10.0.10586.567 and 10.0.15063.0. Is there another way to get this information from a `.dmp`? I delved around inside `curprocess` with stuff like `dx @$curprocess.Threads[0x3508].Stack.Frames`, but I couldn't do things like `dx @$curprocess.Threads[0x3508].Stack.Frames.First()` or `dx @$curprocess.Threads[0x3508].Stack.Frames.Last()`.

Comment: Oh my word, `dx @$curprocess.Threads[0x3508].Stack.Frames.Count()`. Can I build that up now, so I can get the right thread from `dx @$curprocess.Threads` (or somewhere else) and embed that into the `dx` command above, to retrieve the frame count, then use that to control the `.do` loop?

Comment: I can now get the thread ID into `$t0` with `r?`, can I _then_ get the result of `dx @$curprocess.Threads[@$t0].Stack.Frames.Count()` into `$t1`? This `dx` definitely returns the correct number... I just am unaware of how to get that returned number into a pseudo-register. It returns `@$curprocess.Threads[@$t0].Stack.Frames.Count() : 0x24`.

Comment: javascript support has been available in windbg for more than a year now   $curstack is not the command it is @$curstack   no you cant assign a dx into pseudo register ( pseudo register can handle masm not dx expressions)  to use dx expression use javascript  like var foo = host.blah,foo,whatever   you can then manipulate as you wish

Comment: Sure, but `@$curstack` doesn't work in the Windbgs I have available, that's what I meant... it wasn't a typo on my part; I hadn't forgotten the `@` when I used it. So, I can get the frames in the stack with `dx`, but I cannot get that number into a pseudo-register in any way? That's a real shame. I thought I had a solution there.

Comment: Is there any _other_ way apart from `@$curstack.Frames.Count()` and `@$curprocess.Threads[THREAD].Stack.Frames.Count()` (which is probably just a long-hand version of the former) to get a frame count into `$t1`? In your original reply you'd used `@$curstack`, but you'd then hard-coded the `4` it returned for the `.do` (probably for obvious reasons now, I suppose).

Comment: Can everything you can get via `dx` also be got via `??`, or not?

Comment: you are limited if you insist on doing everything from the windbgs command prompt  dx aka native expressions are not assignable to primitive pseudo registers at least not at the moment  they are aldo not assignable to c++ tempraries with r? syntax whether you set true or false to input.usec++expeval  you have to write a javascript  its a simple text file and use .scriptrun as already advised by bill messmer ( msft dbg team ) or as i have done

Comment: You can absolutely utilize 'dx' to assign values to the old pseudo registers ($t0, $t1, etc...).  The result of the 'dx' expression has to be expressible in the old evaluators like '??' (e.g.: no LINQ...  no assignment of synthetic objects like 'Debugger', etc...).  Just do something like "dx @$t0 = @$curthread.Stack.Frames.Count()".

Comment: @ William Messmer i meant it wasn't assignable like r $t0 = @$curthread.Frames.Stack.Count()   for what you do one can also use an uservariable like dx @$foo = @$curxx.yy.zz isnt it ?

Comment: OK - really, really good. Thank you both. On Windbg 10.0.10586.567 the `dx @$t1 = @$curprocess.Threads[@$t0].Stack.Frames.Count()` fails, and returns "Error: Error: Not implemented (0x80004001)", but on Windbg 10.0.15063.0 _it works_ - and that should be good enough for me to progress. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For scripting tasks like this, I would encourage you to take a look at the in-built support for JavaScript (particularly with WinDbg Preview).  Overall, it makes tasks like this significantly easier than the "command/dot scripting" that has been in the debugger for a long time.  The below script shows an example of this:

```
"use strict";

function invokeScript()
{
    for (var frame of host.currentThread.Stack.Frames)
    {
        // Do whatever you want:
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("I just found frame: ", frame, "\n");
    }
}
```

You can run this script in WinDbg Preview with just clicking the "execute" button on the ribbon...  or put it in a file and ".scriptrun FullScriptPath.js".

If there's something it doesn't support that makes you fall back to an older script, we'd certainly love to hear feedback.

Comment: Thank you for that... I know often it should be the "best tool for the job" but - for my own learning experience (I _am_ trying at this) then I'd like to maintain focus on the Windbg scripting. I want to try and get better and better at _this_ aspect (for now).